# Why does the output path for webpack need to be absolute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Whenever you set up Webpack you have to specify an absolute path as the output. Why is this necessary when your entry file is perfectly fine with getting a relative path?

```
const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Just something I was wondering.