# Why does webpack use path module for output path but not for entry file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053381/why-does-the-output-path-for-webpack-need-to-be-absolute).

In the official docs of webpack, there is the following config file:

[webpack.config.js](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#using-a-configuration):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

As you can observe, "entry" uses a relative path, whereas output path uses the `path` module of Node.js.

What is the reason for this inconsistency? Why is it OK to use plain paths for "entry" but not for output path?